# setResult() of Activity not clear

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I am new to Android. I got a scenario in my App as follows :

Imagine activity X starts activity A by `startActivityForResult`. 
Then A starts activity B by setting `Flag_Activity_Forward_Result`..   But A is not finished..   It is in `onPause` state.

If B stops by calling `finish()`,  A which is in background vil come to foreground. 
How can we handle `setResult()` now?

Will `setResult()` in A serve the purpose of sending result to initial caller Activity X?

Comment: Why don't you check by yourself? Simply set result in activity B, finish A without setting result and see if X receives it

Comment: I posted my question only after testing myself..  I finished B..  A's OnResume was called. I set the result there and called finish ().  But X did not receive that result.

Comment: I finished activity B and hence OnResume () of A was called.  There I set the result and called finish ().  But Activity X did not receive it.

Comment: I would try setting result in B, and only doing `finish()` in A